# Trying to remove function argument without code breaking

Tags: javascript, parameters

When I go to remove the argument

```
`tryingtoremove`
```

The code breaks.

It's not being used anywhere else in the code.

How do I remove it without the code breaking?

code https://jsfiddle.net/y78uaqsL/

```
  function createVideoOptions(tryingtoremove, ids) { 
    const options = createOptions(ids);
    return options;
  }
```

Comment: There's just one call of `createVideoOptions()` and its a "private" function. So just change those two places... o.O

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are passed positionally.

You can't get the value of the second argument passed to a function if you don't have a parameter in the second position in the function definition.

You might not want to use the first argument, but you have to put it *somewhere* in order to get the second argument.

Comment: tryingtoremove is not being used in the code, how am I able to remove it?

Comment: @EricaLevine — I just spent three paragraphs explaining why you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the parameter `tryingtoremove` and also modify the function invocation in the following line:

```
    const options = createVideoOptions(video, ids);
```

to this:

```
    const options = createVideoOptions(ids);
```

That should work.

Check how is the final code: https://jsfiddle.net/085yktrx/

Comment: `const options = createVideoOptions(video, ids);` doesn't appear in the question. Presumably it is not modifiable.

Comment: @Quentin `createVideoOptions()` is only available in `makeVideoPlayer()`. So there's no other code that calls or can call `createVideoOptions()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
  function createVideoOptions(ids) {
    // this is bad idea, but it should works
    if (arguments.length>=2) {
      ids = arguments[1]
    }
    const options = createOptions(ids);
    return options;
  }
```